# phpunit not recognise curl while its activated on wamp server

Tags: php, curl, selenium

hi i'am using phpunit with selenium webdriver.
 when i make this cmd 
phpunit myfile
 i get this error message

```
Call to undefined function curl_init().4.3\pear\PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase\Driver.php
```

my code is

```
<?php
class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com/');
    } 
    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->url('http://www.google.com/');
        $this->assertEquals('google', $this->title());
    }

}
?>
```

some says to check my curl i have to cmd  this

```
php --ini
```

but the response outed in many line ,there are some line outed before but hidden
how te see  the previous line on the DOS ?

Comment: What is your question? The error messages is correct. Take care you properly installed PHPUnit before you make use of it. Also this is not inside WAMP server, so the activation within WAMP server is unrelated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPUnit - Call to undefined function curl\_init() error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621615/phpunit-call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-error)

Comment: i have  to mention  that when  installing php unit_selenium 
i used pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/phpunit
because with  pear install phpunit/phpunit_selenium
i got a notification that  php curl not activated
while phpinfo()said  Curl is actived( i edited php.ini from php and apache folder)

how to check/activate php curl for phpunit  if phpinfos() say activated?

Comment: on windows, pear has limited abilities, especially regarding compiling binary libraries that are required as packages. So you need to configure these requirements your own, here the curl extension. It's no magic, just find the correct php.ini for command-line usage. let me know if you've got problems to locate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by copying  php.ini from apache to my php folder.

Answer (score 0):

Enable curl by clicking on wamp server icon on the task bar and click php then select php extension and select curl and also verify that u have this line in your php.ini

```
php extension=php_curl.dll 

for more refer this php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
```

Comment: i did this and phpinfo() confirmed it

Answer (score 0):

Remember that phpunit is probably run in the command line and the command line uses a different php.ini
If you want to find out, which one would be the correct php.ini, just run this command in the command line:

```
php -i | find /i "Configuration File"
```

Comment: you should tell that lost soul first how to install grep on his WAMP computer.

Comment: Ouh you are right. Just posted what I usually do when I need to figure out which php.ini is used.... changed it now to the find command

Comment: i have this

C:\Users\MAI>php -i | find /i "Configuration File"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File => C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini

Comment: then activate CURL in this file!